# Add dwell time for reaching a certain low temperature to the added layer, G-Code for using ANSYS DED process

Tags: g-code

I want to add dwell time like the newly added layer has to cool down to a certain temperature and then the new layer has to be added and so on. Is there any command in G-code for adding dwell time based on temperature.

Comment: You wrote: "`dwell time based on temperature.`", don't you mean "dwell time based on layer print time"? How would you measure the temperature of the print? What is ANSYS DED, maybe move that from the question title and explain in the body of the question?

Comment: The dwell time based on temperature here I meant was that after each layer addition the the printed part has to cool don to a certain temperature before printing the next layer.

Comment: ANSYS DED is an ANSYS add on where we can simulate the DED process. I am asking for code or setting changes required for the dwell time.

Comment: What is DED? Please explain! Furthermore, you don't measure the temperature of the print, but you know the print time of the layer, there are already options on slicers to compensate for short layer deposit times.

Comment: DED-Directed Energy Deposition. Its a type of additive manufacturing process. Look up on the internet for more about it. I am not printing anything physical, its a simulation in ANSYS. The software gets the temperature at every point of the print.